# blender 2.8 fluid fill stops at inflow object height

Tags: fluid-simulation

I create a box domain, small sphere inflow and text letter converted to mesh as an obstacle.
I want to fill the letter with water.
After baking (tried several resolutions 75-220), the fluid flows and fills only up to the inflow source and the water won't get "pushed up" over this line.

In previous blender versions i would play around with the real world meter size param (which i don't see anymore in 2.8) and sometimes this would help but i really didn't understand what i was doing.

Any tips ?
(i want the letters to fill from the bottom up)
[image]

Comment: Increase the inflow velocity.

Comment: My domain time start/end and animation fps are correlated correctly (300 frames, 30 fps, time start -0 time end-10)

Comment: @Yohello1 thanks ! this worked. i changed z velocity from -0.1 to +1m/s. It is as if the water didn't have enough "pressure" to push up the fluid. Now i need to deal with the water that drips out of the letters :)

Comment: what is it set to shell or volume. Also remesh it.